# MODIS flood map

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Searching for flood maps I found [NASA NRT Global Flood Mapping](https://floodmap.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/).

Are there other sites from where I can get flood maps?

Comment: Specifically what area are you looking for ?

Comment: India & Pakistan